# Save current Mouse settings

Tags: mouse, 19.10, settings, scrolling

I am new to Ubuntu, using currently the 19.10 version.

I had an issue in which my mouse wheel click wasn't scrolling, fixed with the following comment:

```
xinput set-prop $deviceId "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" 0, 0, 1
```

Every time I am restarting my computer, the mouse click scrolling isn't working.

Is there a way to save the comment so I won't need to re-apply it every time?

Answer (score 0):

Save that line to a text file: open gedit, paste it into that file and save it inside your Documents directory. Make the script executable (right click, properties).

Then use startup applications to have the script execute. That will start it everything you log into the desktop.

edit: You will need to define `$deviceId` in that script too.

Comment: Thank you, i tried it but nothing is happening after restart. (I followed step-by-step).
1. Created a text file, filled the script line (with my device number).
2. Saved the file, went to properties and checked the "execute" checkbox.
3. Opened Startup applications -> added the text file and saved.
4. restart -> nothing happening.